# How do do check if a list in my aura component is empty

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, aura-if

I have created a list of child contacts of an account and I am looking to have an aura:if statement for if the list is empty or not. I have used the line <aura:if isTrue="isEmpty(v.ContactList)"> but it returns false even if I add a negation to it not(isEmpty(v.ContactList))

**Aura Component**

```
<aura:component controller = "ContactList" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name = "recordId" type = "Id" />
<aura:attribute name = "ContactList" type = "Contact[]"/>
<aura:handler name = "init" value = "{!this}" action = "{!c.getRelatedContactRecords}"/>
<aura:if isTrue="isEmpty(v.ContactList)">
    This account has no contacts
    <aura:set attribute = "else">
        Its not empty
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**Java Script**

```
({
    getRelatedContactRecords : function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        var ContactListInstance = component.get("c.getRelatedContacts");

        ContactListInstance.setParams
        ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        
        ContactListInstance.setCallback(this, function(data) 
            {
                component.set("v.ContactList", data.getReturnValue());
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(ContactListInstance);
    }
})
```

**Apex**

```
public class ContactsList {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getRelatedContacts(Id recordId) {
        return [Select name From Contact Where Account = :recordId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions start with `{!` And end with `}`. Also,  it's just `empty`, not `isEmpty`.

```
isTrue="{!empty(v.ContactList)}"
```